# Removing the Query String

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying different methods for a couple of hours with no joy.

I have 20 or so urls like this

```
http://www.domain.com/news.php?id=77
http://www.domain.com/news.php?id=76
http://www.domain.com/news.php?id=73
```

and so on.

They can all go to 
    http://www.domain.com/news.php

Tried this...
`RewriteRule ^news.php http://www.domain.com/news.php? [R=301,L]`

...but doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule you have is pretty close. You need to check that you actually have a query string.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ /news.php? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^news.php\?id=$ news.php [R=301,L]
```

And recommend this tutorial http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/. It has a nice learn by example approach.